# SQL output delimited file..awk command to read value

Tags: shell, printing, awk, csv

I have sql output delimited file like this:

```
    FD       LD
-------- --------
02-01-11 02-28-11
```

I want to set value of FD as 02-01-11 and LD as 02-28-11 in my c shell script.. I have already done this much in c shell script:

```
sqlplus $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD @${SQL}ex.sql ${TMP}get.tmp
```

set FD=`cat ${TMP}/get_date.tmp | awk 'Begin { FS=" " } { print $1}''
  echo 'FD: '${FD}
set LD=`cat ${TMP}/get_date.tmp 0| awk 'Begin { FS=" " } { print $2}''
  echo 'LD: '${LD}

but this thing is not working.. can some one plz help me to fix this.. i am new to this..dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set FD=`awk '/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]/{print $1}' output.sql`
set LD=`awk '/^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]/{print $2}' output.sql`
```

Comment: Rather than setting that date it set this in my result ------ can you tell me whats wrong with it..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
set FD=`awk '/^[0-9]/{print $1}' output.sql`
set LD=`awk '/^[0-9]/{print $2}' output.sql`
```

and why are you using [cshell](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)?